# Python Library ChatterBot installation Error

Tags: python, chatterbot

```
pip version: 20.1
```

I try to install with python terminal `pip install chatterbot`. it is throwing me following exception:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\burair\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Burair\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site
-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Burair\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ediw4qqw\overlay' --no-wa
rn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem
>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
```

when I try to install the chatterbot from setting interpreter showing this error along with above:

```
Try to run this command from the system terminal. 
Make sure that you use the correct version of `pip` installed for your Python interpreter 
located at F:\PL Work\Document\PycharmProject\ChatBot\venv\Scripts\python.exe.
```

Answer (score 0):

By installing the Version 1.0.0 instead of 1.0.5 it Work!